# How to remove non-greedy suffix from string in bash?

Tags: bash, file-rename

I would like to remove any suffix from a string starting with the last `.svc.` . As a example:

`abc.svc.cluster.local` => `abc`

`abc.svc.svc.cluster.local` => `abc.svc`

`abc.txt` => `abc.txt`

`abc.svc.xyz.svc.zzz` => `abc.svc.xyz`

`svc.xxx` => `svc.xxx` (missing `.` before svc)

If I was doing this is `Go`, I would find the last index of substring `.svc.` and then trim from that index.

How do I do this in bash? Thanks.

Comment: For completeness, please specify in your question what should be the result for, say, the strings `abc.txt`, `abc.svc.xyz.svc.zzz` or `svc.xxx`?

Comment: I have added the answer for these.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
$ v=abc.svc.svc.cluster.local
$ echo ${v%.svc*}
abc.svc
$ v=abc.svc.cluster.local
$ echo ${v%.svc*}
abc
```

And, use `%%` for the greedy behavior:

```
$ v=abc.svc.svc.cluster.local
$ echo ${v%%.svc*}
abc
```

---

According to `man bash`:

> - ${parameter%word}
>   ${parameter%%word}
>
>   The  *word*  is  expanded  to  produce  a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches a **trailing portion** of the expanded value of *parameter*, then the result of  the  expansion is the expanded value of *parameter* with the **shortest** matching pattern (the `%` case) or the **longest** matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted. [...]

Comment: I have added some more examples.

Comment: it should also work for your new examples.

Comment: `[STEP ...]` things make this harder to read

Comment: In this case replacing all prompts with `$` would be way better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename` utility like so:

```
rename --dry-run 's{(.*)[.]svc.*}{$1}' *
```

When satisfied with the planned changes, remove `--dry-run`:

```
rename 's{(.*)[.]svc.*}{$1}' *
```

The command-line utility `rename` comes in many flavors. Most of them should work for this task. I used the [`rename`](https://github.com/ap/rename) version 1.601 by Aristotle Pagaltzis. To install `rename`, simply download its Perl script and place it into `$PATH`. Or install `rename` using `conda`, like so:

```
conda install rename
```

Answer (score 0):

Since is this tagged bash, you can efficiently use `[[ var =~ regex ]]` with parentetical capture groups to fill the `BASH_REMATCH` array with the trimmed filename you want. For example, you can use:

```bash
[[ $var =~ (^.*)[.]svc[.].*$ ]]
```

The `(...)` parenthesis surrounds that portion of the regex that will match up until the last `".svc."` and will capture that text in the `BASH_REMATCH` system array.

This will provide a non-greedy match of `".svc."` preserving everything before the last `".svc."` in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` (the first element `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` contains the entire regex matched). If there is no match of `".svc."`, then no change is made to your filename.

You can put this in a simple script for testing, e.g.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-"abc.svc.cluster.local"}"

if [[ $fname =~ (^.*)[.]svc[.].*$ ]]; then
  printf "%s => %s\n" "$fname" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  printf "%s\n" "$fname"
fi
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your first `"abc.svc.cluster.local"` as the default `fname` you would have:

```
$ bash bash-suffix.sh
abc.svc.cluster.local => abc
```

And for each of your remaining tests in turn:

```
$ bash bash-suffix.sh "abc.svc.svc.cluster.local"
abc.svc.svc.cluster.local => abc.svc
```

```
$ bash bash-suffix.sh "abc.txt"
abc.txt
```

```
$ bash bash-suffix.sh "abc.svc.xyz.svc.zzz"
abc.svc.xyz.svc.zzz => abc.svc.xyz
```

```
$ bash bash-suffix.sh "svc.xxx"
svc.xxx
```

Which match the output you requested. Let me know if you have further questions.